# define sample space (for the first time)

Tags: probability

So I just started to learn n probability theory and I am having some difficult with some simple question.

```
Given 90 students we need to divide them into 3 classes  (30 in each).
define the sample space and calculate it's size.
```

so I think I know how to calculate the size:$\frac{90!}{30!30!30!}$

but how do I define it sample space ?

all my attempts were not good enough because it could be interpreted as something else.

any help would be appreciate !!

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: sample space is collection of all possible choices to divide the students.... Do you wish to know something else?

Comment: I know what does it mean. I meant that I need to write in mathematical language.

Answer (score 2):

You could use set notation to get a "mathematical" statement, although plain english is just as good (if not better) as long as the sample space is not too complicated. Your sample space is pretty simple: It is the class consisting of all partitions of students such that the size (i.e., cardinality) of each set in each partition is 30. In notation, this would be: $\Omega := \{\omega:\#\omega = 3,\#(i\in\omega)=30,i\cap j=\emptyset \;\forall i\neq j  \}$ However, I don't think this adds any insight into the sample space, and so would not be necessary. A verbal defintion like that given by Praphulla above should suffice. "The sample space is the collection of all possible ways to divide the students into three groups of 30."

Hope that helps.